# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

Im attempting to print out my list in formatted way. When I try to parse the list with .item()s it returns *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'* Nothing  ive tried so far has worked.

```
import xmltodict
from collections import defaultdict

dependencyInfo = defaultdict(list)

with open("pom.xml") as f:
    parse_ = xmltodict.parse(f.read()).get('project', {})

    for d in parse_.get("dependencies", {}).get("dependency", []):
        dependencyInfo[d['groupId']].append(
            {"artifactId": d['artifactId'], 'version': d['version']})


    for dependencyId, info in dependencyInfo.items():
        additionalInfo = {}

        for infoName, infoValue in info.items():
            if groupId:
                print(f"groupId = {groupId}")
            if artifactId:
                print(f"artifactId = {artifactId}")
            if version:
                print(f"version = {version}")
            print()
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The error is teling you exactly what the problem is. `info` is a `list`, you are calling `info.items()`, and `list`s don't have `items`.

Comment: as you are using `list` it is obvious of attribute-error because `.items()` is for dictionary operation. you can try converting the list to dict to use `.items()` though it may extend computational cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependencyInfo` is a dictionary whose values are a list of dictionaries. So you will have to get a value from the `dependencyInfo` object and the enumerate over the list of dictionaries.

```
dependencyInfo = defaultdict(list)
dependencyInfo['a'].append({"artifactId": 1, 'version': 1})
dependencyInfo['a'].append({"artifactId": 2, 'version': 2})

# Iterate over the dict
for dependencyId, info_list in dependencyInfo.items():
  # Iterate over the value which is a list of dicts
  for info in info_list:
    # Iterate over each dict
    for infoName, infoValue in info.items():
      print (f"{infoName} = {infoValue}")
```

Output

```
artifactId = 1
version = 1
artifactId = 2
version = 2
```